# how to sort the data in data set i use vb.net and sql database

Tags: sql, vb.net, sorting, dataset

how to sort the data in data set i use vb.net and sql database
my code

```
 Dim SQLSTATMENT As String = "SELECT * FROM   CODES WHERE LEVEL = " & i & ""
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dataadapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLSTATMENT, CONn)
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "codes")


        ds.Tables(0).DefaultView.Sort = "mcode DESC"


        With DataGridView1
            .DataSource = ds
            .DataMember = "CODES"
        End With
```

Comment: you could add it to your SQL query like ORDER BY column1, column2, ... ASC|DESC; - if you just want to use the DataGridView for sorting then you should check out the [DataGridView.SortOrder Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortorder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Your code seems to be ok. What's the problem? It just don't show it in order? Try setting the order (`ds.Tables(0).DefaultView.Sort = "mcode DESC"`) after setting the `Datagridview` data source (after the `With` block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different possibilities:

**Sort on `DataView`:**

```vb
'use the table name to avoid using another table on index 0.
Dim dvTable As DataView = ds.Tables("CODES").DefaultView
dvTable.Sort = "mcode DESC"

With DataGridView1
    .DataSource = dvTable
End With
```

**Sort on `SELECT`:**

```vb
Dim SQLSTATMENT As String = "SELECT * FROM CODES WHERE LEVEL = " & i & " ORDER BY mcode DESC"
```

**Sort on `DataGridView`:**

```vb
With DataGridView1
    .DataSource = ds
    .DataMember = "CODES"
    .Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(DataGridView1.Columns("mcode").Index), ListSortDirection.Descending)
End With
```

Comment: What is the difference between your first possibility and OPs code? PD. I edited your answer just to set the code syntax to vb, as the color highlighting was wrong

Comment: Yeah, I see. The first one is a more secure way not using the table index (numeric).

Comment: Well yes, but as OP is filling the dataset just in that moment, index 0 is going to be the codes datatable. I don't think that has anything to do with the sort problem :)